# Regex: Text the line after a match

Tags: python-3.x, regex

I'm working with a file that has times and values on the next line after the times. I can extract the times into a list but need to get the value of the line following also. This would be a list of time/value pairs.

file looks like this:

```
10:30 AM
F
10:40 AM

10:50 AM
F
11:00 AM
1
11:10 AM

11:20 AM
1
11:30 AM
1
11:40 AM
1
11:50 AM
1
12:00 PM

12:10 PM
1
12:20 PM
1
12:30 PM
1
12:40 PM
1
12:50 PM
1
```

The code i'm using to get the times is this:

```
get_source = driver.page_source  
soup = BeautifulSoup(get_source, 'html.parser')
time_pattern = re.compile(r'\s(\d{1,2}\:\d{2}\s?(?:AM|PM|am|pm))')
times = time_pattern.findall(soup.get_text())
```

Where

```
times = ['10:30 AM', '10:40 AM', '10:50 AM', '11:00 AM'........]
```

I want to also get the value of the next line (blank, F, or 1) creating a time/value pair.

```
timesvaluepair = [[10:30 AM, 'F'],[10:40 AM, ''],[10:50 AM, 'F'],[11:00 AM, '1'],.........]
```

How would you do this?

Comment: The file is not an HTML file. Why do you need BeautifulSoup?

Comment: You can try this `time_pattern = re.compile(r'(\d{1,2}:\d{2}\s?[AP]M)[\r\n]+([a-z\d]?)', re.I)`

Comment: You have a few answers to your question. I noticed that you haven't accepted answers to your question. Any reason why? To put closure to your question, I'd recommend marking one of the answers as accepted and hope you can put closure to other questions you've asked as well.

Comment: Did any of the posted answers work out?

Answer (score 0):

You only need to slightly modify your current regex to capture both the time and value, in separate capture groups:

```py
inp = """10:30 AM
F
10:40 AM

10:50 AM
F
11:00 AM
1
11:10 AM

11:20 AM
1
11:30 AM
1
11:40 AM
1"""

matches = re.findall(r'\b(\d{1,2}\:\d{2}\s?(?:AM|PM|am|pm))\r?\n(\S*)', inp)
print(matches)
```

This prints:

```
[('10:30 AM', 'F'), ('10:40 AM', ''),  ('10:50 AM', 'F'), ('11:00 AM', '1'),
 ('11:10 AM', ''),  ('11:20 AM', '1'), ('11:30 AM', '1'), ('11:40 AM', '1')]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
myfile = open('test.txt', 'r')
lines = myfile.readlines()

dataset = []
item = []
for line in lines:

    line = line.strip()

    if ':' in line:
        if len(item) > 0:
            dataset.append(item)
            item = []

    item.append(line)

dataset.append(item)

print(dataset)
```

Result

```
[['10:30 AM', 'F'], ['10:40 AM', ''], ['10:50 AM', 'F'], ['11:00 AM', '1'], ['11:10 AM', ''], ['11:20 AM', '1'], ['11:30 AM', '1'], ['11:40 AM', '1'], ['11:50 AM', '1'], ['12:00 PM', ''], ['12:10 PM', '1'], ['12:20 PM', '1'], ['12:30 PM', '1'], ['12:40 PM', '1'], ['12:50 PM', '1']]
```

Explanation

- dataset is your final list of pairs
- item is the pair of time and its following line
- we read all lines from the file
- we remove the `\n` from the line with `strip()`
- if the line has a `:` in it, we check if the item has something in it

  - if it does, that means item already has a pair and the pair should be added to dataset
  - empty the item
- add the line back to the item
- keep on doing that till you reach the end; at the end add the item back to the dataset

Answer (score 0):

You might also make it a bit more specific and match a timelike format followed by a newline, and optionally match F or 1 using a character class.

```
\b((?:1[0-2]|0?[1-9]):[0-5][0-9]\s?(?:AM|PM|am|pm))\r?\n([F1]?)
```

**Explanation**

- `\b` A word boundary
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `(?:1[0-2]|0?[1-9])` Match 0-9 with optional leading 0 or 10, 11 12
  - `:[0-5][0-9]\s?` Match from 00 - 59
  - `(?:AM|PM|am|pm)` Match one of the alternatives
- `)` Close group 1
- `\r?\n` Match a newline
- `([F1]?)` Capture group 2, optionally match either F or 1

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/1oH1rw/1) and a [Python demo](https://ideone.com/voYyvp).